# Load data infile into specific column

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a table (named "table_1") with only one column (named "col_1", which is an auto-increment primary key field). There are 100 rows in this column (filled with numbers 1 to 100).

The below code was used to create a new column named "col_2".

```
ALTER TABLE table_1
ADD COLUMN col_2 TINYINT;
```

I have a csv file with only one column and 100 rows, each row filled with one "0" or one "1", and I get an error message when I run the below code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (col_2);
```

Error code: 29. File 'path/to/file.csv' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)

I have already granted NETWORK_SERVICE full access to 'path/to/file.csv', but this problem persists.

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `\` instead of `/` in the path?

Comment: @danblack, could you explain again, please?

Comment: Backslash instead of forwards slash in the path. If that doesn't work try double backslash Sorry got distracted and didn't notice web markups being used.

Comment: @danblack, when I try double backslash, appears the same error code when I try single forwards slash.

Comment: @danblack, let me ask you: when someone load a csv file into a table, it usually adds new rows. But, in fact, I need the table to maintain the same number of rows and  add the data from the csv file into an empty column. The csv file has only one column and the same number of rows as the table.

Comment: [LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/tofile.csv' REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) assuming you've go a csv column that is a primary/unique key. REPLACE replaces the entire row might might/might not be acceptable.

Comment: @danblack, is there a way to mention in the code that the data from the csv file must be loaded in the col_2 in the table?

Comment: CSV with one column. It sound to me its better to either delete the original table and reinsert, or create a new table and update the first one based on the second. This is going in a different direction to resolving your errno 2 in the original question because otherwise your SQL syntax looks fine.